# Jquery datatables amount of pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I'm trying to use [jquery datatables](https://datatables.net/) with backend on Spring HATEOAS which returns HAL document with structure:

```
{
  "_embedded": {...},
  "_links": {...},
  "page": {
    "size": 10,
    "totalElements": 15,
    "totalPages": 2,
    "number": 0
  }
}
```

Currently my datatable settings looks like:

```
const table = TABLE_ELEMENT.DataTable({
    processing: true,
    ordering: false,
    serverSide: true,
    paging: true,
    pagingType: 'numbers',
    pageLength: 10,
    lengthChange: false,
    recordsTotal: 15,

    searching: false,
    ajax: {
      type: 'GET',
      url: '/api/employees',
      dataSrc: data => data._embedded.employees,
    },
    columns: [
      {data: 'name'},
      {data: 'email'},
      {data: 'phone'},
      {data: 'birthDay'}
    ]
  });
```

But the problem is that I can't properly setup number of pages I have. If I use `serverSide: true` my table has infinite amount of pages, if i use `serverSide: false` instead my table has only 1 page. How to solve this?

To switch between pages I use code:

```
TABLE_ELEMENT.on('page.dt', () => {
    table.ajax.url('/api/employees?page=' + table.page.info().page);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to solve this I replaced property `dataSrc`, with:

```
dataFilter: (data) => {
  let json = JSON.parse(data);
  json.recordsTotal = json.page.totalElements;
  json.recordsFiltered = json.page.totalElements;
  json.pageLength = json.page.size;
  json.data = json._embedded.employees;
  return JSON.stringify(json);
}
```

also properties

```
pageLength: 10,
recordsTotal: 15
```

can be removed